# jqgrid adding additional attribute to rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, contextmenu

I want to use contextmenu for my grid but I have an special situation, for each row according to one [or may be more] of its fields value I want to show or hide some of the contextmenu items.

I know i can get the row or even the rowId of right clicked one when binding the contextmenu and show\hide items according to that like this:

```
jQuery(".jqgrow", "#ContextMenuGrid").contextMenu('myMenu1', {
        bindings: {
            'edit': function(t) {
                editRow();
            },
            'add': function(t) {
                addRow();   
            },
            'del': function(t) {
                delRow();
            }
        },
        onContextMenu : function(event, menu)
                        {
                        var rowId = $(event.target).parent("tr").attr("id")
                        var grid = $("#ContextMenuGrid");
                        grid.setSelection(rowId);                                    

                        return true;                                    

                        }
    });             
}
```

now I want to if there is way to add additional attribute to jqgrid rows like "id" that can be retrieved in situation like that to decide upon that!

```
{
"page":1,
"total":83,
"records":830,
"rows":[{"data-custom-data":"data","id":"11067","cell":[...]}]
}
```

my be like the code above or...

Answer (score 0):

You don't included the definition of jqGrid which you use and I don't know `jsonReader` which you use. So I don't know where you save the `"data-custom-data":"data"` of the row. In any way I suppose that you can get the saved data base on the `rowid`.

The `t` parameter (trigger) for all actions ('add', 'edit', 'del') from the `bindings` has `id` property. So your code can be

```
...
bindings: {
    'edit': function(t) {
        editRow(t.id);
    },
....
```